# Special case of Bernouilli Equation using Poiseuille

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I have been explained Poiseuille's Law that states the following:
$$Q = \frac{r^4 \pi (p_1-p_2)}{8\eta L} \quad \text{ and }\quad v_{avg} (r) =\frac{r^2(p_1-p_2)}{8\eta L}$$
Then, I was told that this could be implemented into Bernouilli's equation (which we have only defined for fluids without viscosity) in this specific scenario:
[image: bernouill]

The formula is the following:
$$
p_1 + \rho g h_1 +  \rho \frac{v^2_1}{2} = 
p_2 + \rho g h_2 + \rho \frac{v^2_2}{2} + \frac{8\eta L Q}{\pi r_1^4}
+ \frac{8\eta L Q}{\pi r_2^4}
$$

The last two terms is what I don't understand. Theoretically, they correspond to the viscosity of the fluid, in other words, to the energy that has been dissipated as heat. First thing is, shouldn't it be negative (since work done by friction has always been negative, which makes sanse)? Also, how is this simplification done? I would like to understand where it comes from, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Q = \frac{r^4 \pi (p_1-p_2)}{8\eta L} \quad \text{ and }\quad v_{avg} (r) =\frac{r^2(p_1-p_2)}{8\eta L}
$$
will give you
$$
p_1 - p_2 = \frac{8 \eta L Q}{\pi r^4}\,.
$$
Then you use Bernoulli to account for the pressure difference caused by the height difference and by the velocities at the ends of the pipe, i.e. replace the left-hand side by
$$
p_1 + \rho g h_1 + \frac{v^2_1}{2} -
\left(p_2 + \rho g h_2 + \frac{v^2_2}{2} \right)
$$
and in the right-hand side you make sure to include both sections and replace it with
$$
\frac{8\eta L_1 Q}{\pi r_1^4}
+ \frac{8\eta L_2 Q}{\pi r_2^4}\,.
$$
Done. :)

The last two terms you are wondering about are the pressure drops caused by the viscous forces in the fluid over a length $L$ of pipe with radius $r$.

Comment: So the height difference there in the middle has to "change fast" (have a big slope) for this to work right? Because otherwise we would have to consider the pressure drop by the viscous forces of the slope, which would involve higher level physics I guess. Anyway thanks a lot for the explanation, it really did help!

Comment: I think so too: If the steep connecting bit in the middle is quite long or the bends to extreme or whatever, we would have to include additional, perhaps more complicated effects to calculate the pressure drop. You're welcome.